# C++ remove element from array list

Tags: c++, arraylist

To be practical in the future I'll use standard lib's vector, but right now I'm trying to create some of the basic data structures to better learn C++ (I'm migrating from Java).

I've gotten almost everything working, except for the remove method. I want to get the element I'm removing from the array

```
template <class generic_type> generic_type & ArrayList<generic_type>::remove(const unsigned int index)
{
        check_range_get(index);
        generic_type & temp = data_array[index];
        for(int i=index;i<size()-1;++i)
        {
                data_array[i]=data_array[i+1];
        }
        --number_of_elements;
        return temp;
}
```

The method removes the correct index, so if you have a collection of numbers 0 through 4.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

If we use my remove method is called with index 0 you get:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

HOWEVER, it doesn't return the correct number. It returns `1` instead of returning `0`. I believe that this is because my method overrides the reference to the number in the first index.

To fix this I can change `generic_type & temp` to `generic_type temp`, which will return the correct value, but to my understanding this means that <strike>the value is actually duplicated</strike> a copy is made. For a simple primitive type, this isn't so bad; but for a more complex object with a larger N size in our collection duplication doesn't sound like the best thing that can be done.

Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: I suspect this is the reason that e.g. `vector::pop_back` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Well, you *are* removing the element from your internal array, so you necessarily need to duplicate it (possibly with some optimization via move semantics) and return by value if you want to return it...

Comment: Side hint: `generic_type` is a very uncommon naming scheme for template parameters. I've only ever seen `GENERIC_TYPE` or `GenericType`. And in an extremely generic template like this, `T` is very idiomatic.

Comment: Another side hint: In C++, "to duplicate" is a very non-standard word for what's going on here. It might even confuse people. The correct word is "to copy". You return *copies*, causing calls to the *copy* constructor if the compiler doesn't perform *copy* elision.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. I'm starting a new semester, which slowed me down. Thanks for clarifying the terminology, the only reason I didn't use `T` to begin with was because I thought it was a Java convention. As far as my implementation is concerned, is there any reason I want to copy the objects? Say, for example, I'm using my list to hold edges/nodes in a graph. If I were to remove a node from my list (and potentially make changes to it at the same time EG: a topological sort) if I make a copy any change I make won't reflect the true state of that graph, or am I not getting it?

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this code, one possible solution is to use C++11's move semantics:

```
#include <utility>

generic_type temp{ std::move(data_array[index]) };
```

and return this **by value**, not reference.

Additionally, please note that you are already making A LOT of copies within your loop. You can apply the same technique there:

```
for(int i=index;i<size()-1;++i)
{
        data_array[i] = std::move(data_array[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for educating me on that utility's existence, I'll use it in the future for non-self-educating projects. Can I ask for some clarification? I think (as a newbie) I am misunderstanding something. How am I creating copies if I am handling references? Shouldn't this just be changing their values? Also why should I return the value and not the reference? If I have a node with a list of other nodes, if I need to remove a node and make changes to it: won't those changes be isolated to that copy instead of truly updating the node within the graph? Thanks again for your input, it helps